# A Trie data structure in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, tree, trie

this is the first time I' implementing a Trie. My goal was to make it as simple as possible. So here is the result:
Can I simplify anything else? Are there some things I can change to increase performance ? Also any feedback on code quality/design is welcome :)
Node.java

```
package trie;

public class Node {
    final Node[] children = new Node[26];
    boolean isEnd = false;
}
```

Trie.java

```
package trie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Trie {
    static final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
    final Node root = new Node();

    void add(String str) {
        Node curr = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int idx = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if (curr.children[idx] == null) {
                curr.children[idx] = new Node();
            }
            curr = curr.children[idx];
        }
        curr.isEnd = true;
    }

    Node getNode(String str) {
        Node node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            Node child = node.children[str.charAt(i) - 'a'];
            if (child == null) {
                return null;
            }
            node = child;
        }
        return node;
    }

    boolean contains(String str) {
        Node node = getNode(str);
        return node != null && node.isEnd;
    }

    List<String> prefixedWords(String str) {
        Node curr = getNode(str);
        List<String> prefixedWords = new ArrayList<>();
        DFS(curr, str, prefixedWords);
        return prefixedWords;
    }

    void DFS(Node root, String prefix, List<String> list) {
        if (root != null) {
            if (root.isEnd) {
                list.add(prefix);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
                if (root.children[i] != null) {
                    DFS(root.children[i], prefix + (char) (i + 'a'), list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Magic numbers

> ```
>     final Node[] children = new Node[26];
> ```

Consider changing this to

```
    final Node[] children = new Node[Trie.ALPHABET_SIZE];
```

Now you don't have to manually change the array size if you change the alphabet size.  It may not matter here (we are unlikely to add a letter to the alphabet and you may not need to change alphabets), but it is good practice to set things up so that the system makes them the same.

#### Range-based `for` loops

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
>             int idx = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
> ```

This could be

```
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            int idx = c - 'a';
```

Then you don't have to maintain `i` manually.

You also may want to check that `idx` is in the range 0 to 25.  You currently just trust that that will be so.

#### Early exit

> ```
>     void DFS(Node root, String prefix, List<String> list) {
>         if (root != null) {
> ```

This could be

```
    static void DFS(Node root, String prefix, List<String> list) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
```

This way you don't have to enclose the entire method inside an `if`.  You can just bail out immediately.

The method should be `static` because it doesn't use any of the state of the trie.  In fact, one of its parameters has the same name as an object field.

#### Performance

I don't see anything that leaps out at me performance wise.  Tries are best at prefix searches and relatively slow and memory intensive to build.  For many uses, a `HashSet` (for full word searches) or even an `ArrayList` is faster.  We need a long run to amortize out the build time enough to give faster prefix lookups.

Anyway, time your actual usage to see if this solution is faster than other solutions.